# Restrict internet access to docker container?

Tags: docker

What is the best way to restrict internet access to a single docker container while still forwarding ports?

My current way of doing this works like this:

```
sudo docker network create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 no-internet
sudo docker run --name gitlab -d -p 80:80 -p 822:22 --restart always gitlab/gitlab-ce
sudo docker network connect no-internet gitlab
sudo docker network disconnect bridge gitlab
```

The problem is that if I restart the system the ports are not forwarded anymore:

`sudo docker ps` before reboot:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                             PORTS                                              NAMES
2d2a062744ec        gitlab/gitlab-ce    "/assets/wrapper"   13 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:822->22/tcp   gitlab
```

`sudo docker ps` after reboot:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
2d2a062744ec        gitlab/gitlab-ce    "/assets/wrapper"   12 minutes ago      Up 2 minutes (healthy)                       gitlab
```

Comment: Have you tried `--network no-internet` on the `docker run` command? And in that case I think you could drop the last two commands.

Comment: @DanLowe I have, but then I run into the problem that the ports are not forwarded, resulting in the same as with my current solution after rebooting.

Comment: I'm not certain what you want is possible just using network commands. You may be better off using something like iptables inside the container to block whatever traffic you don't want to escape.

Comment: You can't edit iptables inside of an unprivileged container, that capability has been intentionally removed from the root user.

Comment: You'll probably need to open up a feature request with [libnetwork](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues) to get `--internal` and a published port working together.

Comment: @Dan Lowe: Did you mean --network=none?

Comment: @herm No, I was using the user’s example network named `no-internet`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So if I understand your scenario correctly, you would like to avoid sharing your host's network to your gitlab container to make sure gitlab cannot connect to the internet. At the same time you wish to share the host's network to bind a container port to your host system. It doesn't work that way, but the following might be an acceptable workaround for you: docker containers sharing the same internal network can connect to exposed/published ports of other containers on the same network.

You could follow this approach:

- Run a reverse proxy in front of your gitlab container
- The reverse proxy is member of your internal network and the default bridge network (which includes the host's net)
- This enables the reverse proxy to bind to a host port and forward requests to your gitlab container while gitlab still can't access the internet

I quickly put this example together, hope that gets you started:

`docker network create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 no-internet`

`docker network create internet`

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    container_name: whoami
    networks:
      - no-internet

  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.13-alpine 
    container_name: proxy
    networks:
      - internet
      - no-internet
    volumes:
      - ./vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"

networks:
  internet:
    external:
      name: internet
  no-internet:
    external:
      name: no-internet
```

`vhost.conf`:

```
upstream whoami {
    server whoami:8000;
}

server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://whoami;
    }
}
```

Please note the above mentioned `internet` network is actually not needed, as a docker container shares the host network by default anyway. It's just there to make things clearer.

In the example depicted above, open `http://localhost/` and you will see the response of the `whoami` container, the `whoami` container itself however can't connect to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `internal:true` to disable internet connectivity:

```
networks:
  yournetwork:
     internal: true
```