# Creating a secure environment for untrusted python code

Tags: python, security, sandbox, execution

I'm writing an application where we need to execute untrusted python code. (i.e. an application similar to a homework submission server, where student input is untrusted)

Thinking about it, my first thought is that by disabling the file I/O capabilities of the language (and thus, restrict code to using stdin/stdout only), a program couldn't do much harm to the system.

Is this correct, or are there attack vectors that I haven't thought of?

Is there some kind of python flag or compiler option that I can pass to isolate the code?

Comment: Years ago there was a try to implement such an environment as part of standard library. It was abandoned because it seems that even the Python developers were unable to make it really secure. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/rexec.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sandbox Python in pure Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139/how-can-i-sandbox-python-in-pure-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run them in docker containers!

- [Restrict their resources](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)
- [Restrict network access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001200/restrict-internet-access-to-docker-container)
- [Detailed security information](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/)
- [Discussion about security](https://forums.docker.com/t/is-docker-suitable-for-running-untrusted-code/7640/4)

As with anything about security, there is no silver bullet. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't execute arbitrary code on your machine using any of the python sandboxing methods since security professional demonstrated several time how they are escapable.
[Escaping the python sandbox](http://www.slideshare.net/tzanany/escaping-the-python-sandbox)

I would suggest running the code inside a docker container with a new user with restricted permissions.

[Hardening Linux Containers](https://gist.github.com/FrankSpierings/5c79523ba693aaa38bc963083f48456c)

Lastly, you can try to parse the python code into an AST and go down the levels to make sure that dangerous actions are not present.

My choice would be using a docker container, preferably an Alpine version with restricted access.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/openedx/codejail. This package is also available on PyPI and is used and maintained by tech giants like Open edX and AWS